# How can I create a dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, python, forms, flask, post

I'm trying to build an interactive Form with Flask. Specifically, its a form made for teachers to make a quiz. Every question has multiple answers. Everything needs to be done dynamically since every question may have a different number of answers, and each quiz may have a different number of questions.

When the user clicks on a button, a new input field gets added with Javascript. Each field is a new `<input type="text" required>`. Here's a sample of the HTML. Everything in the `<div` with `id="quiz"` is  being dinamically generated with javascript and some buttons.

```html
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="course">Select the course</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="course" id="course" required="">

            <option value="1">Course 1</option>

            <option value="2">Course 2 </option>

        </select>

        <div class="quiz" id="quiz">

            <div class="question">
                <input type="text" id="1" required>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input type="text" id="4" required>
                    <label>Correct?</label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input type="text" id="6" required>
                    <label>Correct?</label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </div>
                <div class="answer">
                    <input type="text" id="8" required>
                    <label>Correct?</label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
               </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Expected behaviour**

With Flask, I should be able to do something like this and get all the fields that have been added

```py
@dashboard.route('/newQuiz', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def newQuiz():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form) #immutableMultiDict with all the data
```

**What Happens**
`request.form` only returns the `course` selection. The `course` is the only thing that is being generated in Python. Every other input that has been added with JS is NOT present in the `POST` request.

How can I add this dynamic content into the `POST` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here to give an answer for my own question, since I figured out that the behaviour I was looking for is "not a thing" in Flask. I had to manually get everything in the form with Javascript, make a AJAX request to the server and refresh the page.

```js
fetch(`${window.location}`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(quiz), //this should be your object
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: new Headers({
            "content-type": "application/json"
        })
    }) //getting the response back
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log(`Response status was ${response.status}`)
                return;
            }

            response.json().then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                location.reload(); // this is needed if you want to flash messages!
            })
        })
```

and then, with python

```py
@yourBlueprint.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def something():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        quiz = request.get_json() # this is now a dictionary, do whatever you want with it!
        flash("Okie dokie, i've received your stuff") 
        return make_response(jsonify({'message': 'hello from the other side'}), 200)
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

EDIT
I was wrong. The method above works, but it was a big oopsie on my end. `input` tags NEED a `name` attribute in order to be accessible in the `ImmutableMultiDict` Object. To sum it up, the code in the initial post works, but you need to add a `name` attribute in every `input` tag.

```html
<div class="answer">
  <input type="text" id="4" name="text1" required>
  <label>Correct?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">
</div>
```